# getting module java.xml does not "opens javax.xml.namespace" to unnamed module

Tags: java, spring, maven-3, spring-data-mongodb, tomcat10

I have upgraded my maven project From Java 8 to Java 17 i have resolved all compilation errors , but I am getting error in MongoDb initialisation while deploying tomcat server locally.

Exception :

```
ERROR ContextLoader Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in com.project.app.config.web.DbConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingMongoConverter' parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in com.project.app.config.web.DbConfig: Unable to make field private final java.lang.String javax.xml.namespace.QName.namespaceURI accessible: module java.xml does not "opens javax.xml.namespace" to unnamed module @e416d24
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:550)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:394)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:274)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4452)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4892)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1821)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:376)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in com.project.app.config.web.DbConfig: Unable to make field private final java.lang.String javax.xml.namespace.QName.namespaceURI accessible: module java.xml does not "opens javax.xml.namespace" to unnamed module @e416d24
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.String javax.xml.namespace.QName.namespaceURI accessible: module java.xml does not "opens javax.xml.namespace" to unnamed module @e416d24
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:787)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:339)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoManagedTypes.forEach(MongoManagedTypes.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:484)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractMappingContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
    ... 72 more
```

DBConfig class

```
package com.project.app.config.web;

import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ReadPreference;
import com.project.dao.mongodb.config.MongoAuditAware;
import com.project.rest.utils.JSR310DateConverters.DateToZonedDateTimeConverter;
import com.project.rest.utils.JSR310DateConverters.ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.EnableMongoAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.WriteResultChecking;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.LoggingEventListener;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.ValidatingMongoEventListener;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by prateek on 3/2/17.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.project.dao.mongodb"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.project.dao.mongodb.*", "com.project.dao.redisdb.*"})
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class DbConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DbConfig.class);

    @Value("${db.name}")
    private String dbName;

    @Value("${db.host}")
    private String dbHost;

    @Value("${db.port}")
    private int dbPort;

    @Value("${db.totalConnection}")
    private int connectionPerHost;

    @Value("${db.gridFs.uri}")
    private String gridFsUri;

    @Value("${db.client.uri}")
    private String mongoUri;

    @Value("${db.batchSize}")
    public static int batchSize = 50;

    @Override
    protected void configureClientSettings(MongoClientSettings.Builder builder) {
        builder.applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(mongoUri));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return dbName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Collection<String> getMappingBasePackages() {
        return Arrays.asList("com.project.all", "com.project.nextgen.*", "com.project.metrics.*", "com.project.config.*");
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Initializing mongo template with dbName [{}]", dbName);
        MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory = new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(mongoUri);
        MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(
                new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDatabaseFactory), new MongoMappingContext());

        mappingMongoConverter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
        mappingMongoConverter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));
        mappingMongoConverter.afterPropertiesSet();
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDatabaseFactory, mappingMongoConverter);
        mongoTemplate.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION);
        logger.debug("Initialization of mongo template completed successfully with URI {}", mongoUri);
        return mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory = new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(gridFsUri);

        MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(
                new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDatabaseFactory), new MongoMappingContext());

        GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate = new GridFsTemplate(mongoDatabaseFactory, mappingMongoConverter);

        logger.debug("Initialization of mongo grid fs template completed successfully with URI {}", gridFsUri);

        return gridFsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name = "mongoSecondaryBean")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplateSecondaryPreference() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Initializing mongo template with dbName [{}]", dbName);

        MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory = new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(mongoUri);
        MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(
                new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDatabaseFactory), new MongoMappingContext());

        mappingMongoConverter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
        mappingMongoConverter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));
        mappingMongoConverter.afterPropertiesSet();

        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDatabaseFactory, mappingMongoConverter);

        mongoTemplate.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION);
        mongoTemplate.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred());

        logger.debug("Initialization of mongo template completed successfully with URI {}", mongoUri);
        return mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator().getValidator());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureConverters(MongoCustomConversions.MongoConverterConfigurationAdapter converterConfigurationAdapter) {
        converterConfigurationAdapter.registerConverter(DateToZonedDateTimeConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterConfigurationAdapter.registerConverter(ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter.INSTANCE);
    }

    @Bean(name = "mongoAudit")
    public AuditorAware<String> mongoAuditProvider() {
        return new MongoAuditAware();
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggingEventListener mappingEventsListener() {
        return new LoggingEventListener();
    }
}
```

**Dependencies** :

1. spring : 6.0.8,
2. spring-data-mongodb : 4.0.0,
3. mongodb-driver-core : 4.8.0,
4. mongodb-driver-sync : 4.8.0
5. JDK : 17.0.7
6. Maven : 3.8.1
7. Tomacat : 10.1.10
8. lombok : 1.18.28
9. IDE : IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.3 (Ultimate Edition)
   Runtime version: 11.0.10+8-b1145.96 amd64

Iam not sure if the problem is with incorrect dependencies versions or i have done something wrong in mongoDB initialization

Please help in in understanding if I am doing something wrong. i have tried other solutions like adding --add-opens=java.xml/javax.xml.namespace=ALL-UNNAMED in idea64.vmoptions file but my problem is not resolved yet.
Thanks in advance.

NOTE :
I have debugged the code and found that below field is causing the issue, and this is getting used in another class also, but Iam not sure why this error is caused by JAXBElement. Please let me know if anyone has any explanation.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
                        @Data
                        @AllArgsConstructor
                        @NoArgsConstructor
                        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                                "content"
                        })
                        public static class REMARKS {


                            @XmlElementRef(name = "REMARK", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
                            @JsonProperty("aContent")
                            @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                            protected List<JAXBElement<String>> content;

                        }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).